# tar --files-from with wildcard inside the list

Tags: bash

I'm trying to compress list of files from a text file (`include.txt`):

```
/var/dir/1/some_file_number*.txt
/var/dir/1/some_file_number*.log
```

and exclude from a list (`exclude.txt`):

```
/var/dir/1/some_file_number_exclude*.*
```

with command

```
tar -cf archive.tar --files-from="/to/my/dir/include.txt" --exclude-from="/to/my/dir/exclude.txt"
```

It seems to work for the `--exclude-from`, but doesn't for `--files-from`, I gets error saying that:

```
tar: /var/dir/1/some_file_number*.txt: Warning: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: /var/dir/1/some_file_number*.log: Warning: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

Seems like tar couldn't expand the asterisk in `--files-from`, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: could you try reversing the order? --exclude-from before --include-from

Comment: I don't see how that will makes any difference, but yes, it's the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function that expands glob patterns from a file, and execute it inside process substitutions.

```
function expand_glob_file {
    local patterns __
    readarray -t patterns < "$1" || return

    for __ in "${patterns[@]}"; do
        compgen -G "$__"
    done
}

tar -cf archive.tar --files-from=<(expand_glob_file /to/my/dir/include.txt) --exclude-from=<(expand_glob_file /to/my/dir/exclude.txt)
```

Comment: This works perfect even with white-spaces, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `tar` doesn't support pattern matching when creating an archive. From [this documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/controlling-pattern_002dmatching.html#controlling-pattern_002dmatching):

> There are no inclusion members in create mode (‘--create’ and ‘--append’), since in this mode the names obtained from the command line refer to files, not archive members.

For other operations such as `--extract`, you could use the `--wildcards` flag but apparently creating an archive is an exception.

One idea is you could first expand the wildcards in your include file using something like

```sh
xargs -I @ bash -c "printf '%s\n' @" < /to/my/dir/include.txt > /tmp/include.txt
mv /tmp/include.txt /to/my/dir/include.txt
```

and then run your `tar` command from before. Note: this doesn't handle spaces in file paths well (and possibly many other things since it relies on shell expansion), but konsolebox's answer seems to support that.

Comment: But [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) You can replace `ls -l` with `printf '%s\n'`

Comment: That's really a good workaround, any idea how to tweak this to works with path that includes whitespace, eg `/var/another path/file.*`?

Comment: Looks like @konsolebox's answer handles spaces well.